# How I can check that I have a password for login to my notebook

Tags: command-line, user-accounts

How I can check that I have a password for login to my notebook, but no using method to log out and log in to see if it requires password.

Comment: Try `RunAs` to start any command-line utility (CMD.EXE with any fake command, for example) using your own login name and empty password (`echo.|runas /user:yourlogin "cmd.exe /c echo on"`). If password is set, execution fails.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Settings -> Accounts -> Sign-in options.
If the password is not set, red caption will appear atop: "You must add a password before you can use the other sign-in options".

Answer (score 1):

*runas /u:domain\username notepad.exe*

The utility will prompt for the password, if the right password has been provided, notepad will launch, if not it will produce error 1326: the username or password is incorrect

[image]

source:

https://serverfault.com/questions/67706/tool-to-test-a-user-account-and-password-test-login

Comment: Not sure if how big a deal it is but when you were redacting your username from the screenshot you missed one - *Enter the password for...*